# TravisCI test elasticsearch error with Python 2, ok for Python 3

Tags: python, elasticsearch, travis-ci

My tests in travis recently failed when connecting to elasticsearch.
I have the error, for Python 2.x :

```
ConnectionError: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', ResponseNotReady())) caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', ResponseNotReady()))
```

For Python 3.x (same code), it works fine.

Any idea of what is going wrong ? Everything was fine some time ago.

Comment: What code is causing this error? It's impossible to help without more context.

Comment: It is a simple python elasticsearch connection, using pypi package. It works locally on my computer and it works with the python3 env on travis, only python 2 env fails with this error.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem and saw your post was posted for only a few hours. After some digging, I found that urllib3 version 1.11 breaks elasticsearch for some reason. I pinned my version to urllib3==1.10.3 and it seems to be working.

Comment: I gonna test this, i wonder however why it works with python3. My code in travisci is tested for both envs.